# How to save variant information inside MYSQL

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I am saving product information to MySQL 5.7 and now want to add info on product variants.

What would be the prefered approach to store variant information inside a relational db?

e.g.

Product table:

```
ARTICLE_NO | NAME
123          example
124
125
126
127
128
```

Solution 1, table variants

```
VARIANT_ID | ARTICLE_NO | 
1            123
1            124
2            126
2            127
2            128
```

Solution 2: Possible alternative, everything in the prod table:

```
ARTICLE_NO | NAME     | VARIANTS
123          example    123,124
124                     123,124
125
126                     126,127,128
127                     126,127,128
128                     126,127,128
```

With solution 1, the variant ID has to be created programatically, autoincrement does not work here. E.g. in case there is an additional variant of a given product, one needs to get the variant id if exists. If not create new one

With solution 2 there is duplicated data and seems "dirty" to handle.

What would you recommend how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to "group" products as variants of each other.

I would create a `VariantGroups` table that has an auto-increment id.

```
CREATE TABLE VariantGroups (
  variant_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then the product table may have a reference to the variant-group to which it belongs.

```
ARTICLE_NO | NAME     VARIANT_ID
123          example    1
124                     1
125                     2
126                     3
127                     3
128                     3
```

It's up to you if you want to give product 125 a "group" since it's the only variant. But that would make it easy to add another product to the group later.

Comment: Not sure if I explained it well. Example there are 3 product IDs and all are variants of each other. The product table has an entry for each of those. I tried your example but what should be the variant ID and how to make sure all variants have the same?

Comment: I've rewritten the answer above given my better understanding of what you're doing.